# More volatile sequence than "classical"

Tags: f#

For cartesian production there is a good enough function - *sequence* which defined like that:

```
let rec sequence = function 
  | []      -> Seq.singleton [] 
  | (l::ls) -> seq { for x in l do for xs in sequence ls do yield (x::xs) }
```

but look at its result:

> > sequence [[1..2];[1..10000]] |> Seq.skip 1000 ;;
> >     val it : seq = seq [[1; 1001]; [1; 1002]; [1; 1003]; [1; 1004]; ...]

As we can see the first "coordinate" of the product alters very slowly and it will change the value when the second list is ended.

I wrote my own sequence as following (comments below):

```
/// Sum of all producted indeces = n
let rec hyper'plane'indices indexsum maxlengths =
    match maxlengths with 
    | [x]        -> if indexsum < x then [[indexsum]] else []
    | (i::is)   -> [for x in [0 .. min indexsum (i-1)] do for xs in hyper'plane'indices (indexsum-x) is do yield (x::xs)]
    | []        -> [[]]

let finite'sequence = function
    | [] -> Seq.singleton []
    | ns -> 
        let ars = [ for n in ns -> Seq.toArray n ]
        let length'list = List.map Array.length ars
        let nmax = List.max length'list
        seq { 
            for n in [0 .. nmax] do 
            for ixs in hyper'plane'indices n length'list do 
                yield (List.map2 (fun (a:'a[]) i -> a.[i]) ars ixs) 
        }
```

The key idea is to look at (two) lists as at (two) orthogonal dimensions where every element marked by its index in the list. So we can enumerate all elements by enumerating every element in every section of cartesian product by hyper plane (in 2D case this is a line). In another words imagine excel's sheet where first column contains values from [1;1] to [1;10000] and second - from [2;1] to [2;10000]. And "hyper plane" with number 1 is the line that connects cell A2 and cell B1. For the our example

> > hyper'plane'indices 0 [2;10000];; val it : int list list = [[0; 0]]
> >     hyper'plane'indices 1 [2;10000];; val it : int list list = [[0; 1]; [1; 0]]
> >     hyper'plane'indices 2 [2;10000];; val it : int list list = [[0; 2]; [1; 1]]
> >     hyper'plane'indices 3 [2;10000];; val it : int list list = [[0; 3]; [1; 2]]
> >     hyper'plane'indices 4 [2;10000];; val it : int list list = [[0; 4]; [1; 3]]

Well if we have indeces and arrays that we are producing from the given lists than we can now define sequence as {all elements in plane 0; than all elements in plane 1 ... and so on } and get more volatile function than original *sequence*.

But *finite'sequence* turned out very gluttonous function. And now the question. How I can improve it?

With best wishes, Alexander. (and sorry for poor English)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do, but have you considered using the simple cartesian function to pre-populate an array, then doing index lookups on that array to extract the subsequences/patterns you want? Seems like it might be simpler.

Comment: I'd like to simplify.I'd like to get rid of arrays at all. See please (for brevity) comments to @toyvo. Prepopulation is not always possible. In my case it's easy to get 10 arrays by 1e5 elements in every one as arguments for cartesian production. Good example of what I'm doing(not so effectively maybe) is _quickcheck_-like generator. You take 10 arrays of wchar by 1000 symbols and try to make string of length 10. I have imagination about C# solution, but I'd like to have more or less concise functional one. So I try. If you have any ideas or propositions feel free email *me at gmail.com. Tnx

Comment: @alexander.vladislav.popov ah, so your application is *quickcheck*. This means you can use random sampling? That could drastically reduce your universes. Or are you trying to do exhaustive testing?

Comment: @toyvo _quickcheck_ stands for grasp only. We need exhaustive testing ( and all universes as well :) ). The goal is to generate strings (I like _genex_ mot), possibly all, satisafying to a given regex

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain what exactly is the problem - time or space complexity or performance? Do you have a specific benchmark in mind? I am not sure how to improve on the time complexity here, but I edited your code a bit to remove the intermediate lists, which might help a bit with memory allocation behavior.

Do not do this:

```
for n in [0 .. nmax] do
```

Do this instead:

```
for n in 0 .. nmax do
```

Here is the code:

```ml
let rec hyper'plane'indices indexsum maxlengths =
    match maxlengths with
    | [] -> Seq.singleton []
    | [x] -> if indexsum < x then Seq.singleton [indexsum] else Seq.empty
    | i :: is ->
        seq {
            for x in 0 .. min indexsum (i - 1) do
                for xs in hyper'plane'indices (indexsum - x) is do
                    yield x :: xs
        }

let finite'sequence xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> Seq.singleton []
    | ns -> 
        let ars = [ for n in ns -> Seq.toArray n ]
        let length'list = List.map Array.length ars
        let nmax = List.max length'list
        seq {
            for n in 0 .. nmax do
                for ixs in hyper'plane'indices n length'list do
                    yield List.map2 Array.get ars ixs
        }
```

Does this fare any better? Beautiful problem by the way.

**UPDATE:** Perhaps you are more interested to mix the sequences fairly than in maintaining the exact formula in your algorithm. Here is a Haskell code that mixes a finite number of possibly infinite sequences fairly, where fairness means that for every input element there is a finite prefix of the output sequence that contains it. You mention in the comment that you have a 2D incremental solution that is hard to generalize to N dimensions, and the Haskell code does exactly that:

```haskell
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] y          = y
merge x []          = x
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys

prod :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
prod _ [] _ = []
prod _ _ [] = []
prod f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : a `merge` b `merge` prod f xs ys where
  a = [f x y | x <- xs] 
  b = [f x y | y <- ys]

prodN :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
prodN []     = [[]]
prodN (x:xs) = prod (:) x (prodN xs)
```

I have not ported this to F# yet - it requires some thought as sequences do not match to head/tail very well.

**UPDATE 2:**

A fairly mechanical translation to F# follows.

```
type Node<'T> =
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'T * Stream<'T>

and Stream<'T> = Lazy<Node<'T>>

let ( !! ) (x: Lazy<'T>) = x.Value
let ( !^ ) x = Lazy.CreateFromValue(x)

let rec merge (xs: Stream<'T>) (ys: Stream<'T>) : Stream<'T> =
    lazy
    match !!xs, !!ys with
    | Nil, r | r, Nil -> r
    | Cons (x, xs), Cons (y, ys) -> Cons (x, !^ (Cons (y, merge xs ys)))

let rec map (f: 'T1 -> 'T2) (xs: Stream<'T1>) : Stream<'T2> =
    lazy
    match !!xs with
    | Nil -> Nil
    | Cons (x, xs) -> Cons (f x, map f xs)

let ( ++ ) = merge

let rec prod f xs ys =
    lazy
    match !!xs, !!ys with
    | Nil, _ | _, Nil -> Nil
    | Cons (x, xs), Cons (y, ys) ->
        let a = map (fun x -> f x y) xs
        let b = map (fun y -> f x y) ys
        Cons (f x y, a ++ b ++ prod f xs ys)

let ofSeq (s: seq<'T>) =
    lazy
    let e = s.GetEnumerator()
    let rec loop () =
        lazy
        if e.MoveNext()
            then Cons (e.Current, loop ())
            else e.Dispose(); Nil
    !! (loop ())

let toSeq stream =
    stream
    |> Seq.unfold (fun stream ->
        match !!stream with
        | Nil -> None
        | Cons (x, xs) -> Some (x, xs))

let empty<'T> : Stream<'T> = !^ Nil
let cons x xs = !^ (Cons (x, xs))
let singleton x = cons x empty

let rec prodN (xs: Stream<Stream<'T>>) : Stream<Stream<'T>> =
    match !!xs with
    | Nil -> singleton empty
    | Cons (x, xs) -> prod cons x (prodN xs)

let test () =
    ofSeq [
        ofSeq [1; 2; 3]
        ofSeq [4; 5; 6]
        ofSeq [7; 8; 9]
    ]
    |> prodN
    |> toSeq
    |> Seq.iter (fun xs ->
        toSeq xs
        |> Seq.map string
        |> String.concat ", "
        |> stdout.WriteLine)
```

Comment: thank you Toyvo very much indeed. Better? Not at all, sorry. But problem is in conversion seq->array. When sequence is big enough an array takes significant place for storage. I made this algorithm as desperate gesture. For example at some circumstances version with _finite'sequence_ takes 700M when with _sequence_ - only 20M. I have functional solution (on paper only) for 2-D. The idea: you are simly enumerating like snake - a1,b1,a2,a3,b2 .. and so on. But I have no genalization for n-D. That is the beautiful problem. To construct snake version of _sequence_.

Comment: I do not think it will work. Your alg needs to go forward *and backward*, so you cannot work with `seq` - `seq` only goes forward. `array` gives you random access but that costs memory. Where is your input data coming from (the input sequences)? You may design a DS with array-like interface but less memory use to fit that. For example, if data comes from a file, you may design a DS to seek back and forth in that file.

Comment: This is exactly what I need from Haskell. It would be great to have analogous solution for F#. Maybe LazyList?

Comment: Yes, I guess using a lazy list would be the simplest, though it has a lot of runtime overhead. See my mechanical translation above. I am a bit apprehensive it is not going to perform well, but give it a try - it all depends on your usage.

Comment: @alexander.vladislav.popov please let me know what you end up with. It is really a curious problem.

Comment: Ok. I have last week before vacation (time of return about Aug 10) so no time for experiments, githubbing etc. I planed to make open source project and place my package into the public domain. You can pick it up if you want. Or simply play with it. Let me know your email and I will send you whole solution (very small). It's public sharable. My email - alexander.vladislav.popov at gmail.com.